# Windows 10 mscoreei.dll could not be loaded

Tags: windows, react-native, powershell, android-studio

I'm running Windows 10 . Several programs crash and display an error that mscoreei.dll could not be loaded. Like while write a choco update command on cmd and when installing POSTMAN. I executed sfc /scannow and watched videos but none of them have help. Please tell me what to do

Error Picture

[image: 1]

Comment: Please post the error as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you install C++ redistributable? https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe
If you have, check if you have install Java.
C++ Build Tool if the 2 above didn't work

Comment: mscore is .net, not c++

Comment: C# or not, it still use the same libs, dll as C++